# Maven multi module, dependency between modules

Tags: maven

I created a maven multi modules project with 2 modules: core and service.
Service module is using core module (core is declared as a dependency on service module).
The parent pom version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT (so the modules too).
During the maven clean package phase, maven is not fetching core module neither from my local repo nor from remote repo (nexus). It is always building with core module within the project and not fetching any more recent SNAPSHOT version from repo (local/remote).
Is that the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you build the project, it will build everything. The command `clean package` will resolve the inter-module dependencies inside the project.

Everything else would probably lead to surprising results.

If you really just want to build just one module, use the `-pl` parameter.

Comment: it seems when modules has same version as the parent pom (here it is 1.0-SNAPSHOT), maven will resolve  the inter-module dependencies inside the project. Now, let's assume, module service is not using module core 1.0-SNAPSHOT version but it is using module core1.0. In this case maven will fetch the core-1.0 from local/remote repo.
So, is it normal that maven will fetch for module-dependency only if the the version is different than the parent one? (so in case modules and parent is having same version, so maven will resolve dependency within the project only. Is this the right behaviour?)